# Spring Integration wire tap benefits

Tags: spring, integration

Can anyone tell me what are the benefits of using wiretap in spring integration? we have some cron jobs that reads incoming file and process it and updated DB.
we also have splunk tool and we are using SL4J library for all web code(controller, facade, services). Splunk indexes log files which are dumped using SL4J.

But we have been asked to use wiretap for integration code?  I wanted to know what are benefits.